# How to Switch Top and Bottom Panel Bars in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: customization, panel, mate, appearance

I am currently running Ubuntu MATE, and I am wondering if there is a way to simply switch the top and bottom panel bars. I want the bar with the 'Applications' menu and the task bar on the bottom, and the bar with the 'hide all windows and show the desktop' button and the screen selector at the top. Considering that Linux is open and infinitely customizable, this should be doable.

I have looked in the preferences / options / menu editor, and have not found a way to do this beyond changing the layout to that of a different DE, none of which I like. That being said, I may be overlooking something.

I can use the command line if necessary, but I have no idea what code to use to implement this change...

Thanks in advance for any help / insight you can provide : )

Answer (score 3):

After fiddling around with it a bit more, I found that you can simply right click on the menu panels, select 'Properties' and change 'Orientation' from 'Top' to 'Bottom' and vice-versa (no jokes, please).

It's easy.

I will leave this question up instead of deleting it, because perhaps this may help others who are experiencing the same problem due to noob ignorance.